# requestStorageAccess Failure

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, storage-access-api

When I ask for storage access on a page in my iframe, It returns "Undefined".

What does that signify?   I was hoping for a True, and would have understood false.  (it was denied) but what does Undefined mean in this context? What went wrong?

```
<button id="start-button">Start Puctto</button>

<script>

function gain_access() {
  document.cookie = "foo=bar";              // set a cookie
  document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
    if (!hasAccess) {     
      return document.requestStorageAccess();
    }
  }).then(_ => {   
    // Now we have first-party storage access!
    // Let's access some items from the first-party cookie jar
    document.cookie = "foo=bar";              // set a cookie
    localStorage.setItem("username", "John"); // access a localStorage entry
    window.opener.postMessage('set_session', '*');   
    window.location.href = document.referrer;
  }).catch(_ => {
    alert(_);
  });
}
  document.getElementById('start-button').addEventListener('click', function (){
    console.log('Start button clicked');                
    gain_access();

  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anything went wrong. Have you checked to see if the value was set correctly?

`localStorage.setItem` doesn't return anything even if it works, so when that's printed to the console, it shows `undefined` i.e. it's trying to print the return value but there isn't one so the return value is `undefined`.

Don't rely on a return value from it to do something else, just kind of take it for granted.

If it is setting the value correctly to `localStorage` then it's all good.

EDIT: Also, apparently the concept of requesting storage access is still [only at proposal stage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasStorageAccess), so maybe just remove that part all together.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Safari won't allow session storage without requesting storage access, so although its all a bit beta, it is needed.

Comment: Ah I see - it's a Safari thing. My bad, had never encountered that

Comment: you will, ha ha.  its coming to everybrowser.

Comment: You will need it for firefox 102...